# Display x amount of products from category x in right / left block (similar to related products)

Tags: product, blocks

I'd like to display 4 random products from a specific category on the right hand side of my product page. The effect I'd like to achieve is exactly like the *Related Products* and *Compare Products* block that appear under those conditions.

So far I've taken the code from **related.phtml** and placed it in another file and updated my templates *layout.xml*.

However looking at the code, I cannot see where I would call a category or specify how many products to display.

How can I use the **related.phtml** file as a template to display 4 random products from a specific category in the right block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `related.phtml` template as long as the block behind it passes a collection as expected. Create a custom extension with a block class something like this below

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Related extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Related
{

    protected function _prepareData()
    {
        [...]

        $this->_itemCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('...') // whatever you need
            ->addCategoryFilter($category) // category is an instance of Mage_Catalog_Model_Category
            ->setPageSize(4);

        $this->_itemCollection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));

        if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_Checkout')) {
            Mage::getResourceSingleton('checkout/cart')->addExcludeProductFilter($this->_itemCollection,
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId()
            );
            $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($this->_itemCollection);
        }

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($this->_itemCollection);

        $this->_itemCollection->load();

        foreach ($this->_itemCollection as $product) {
            $product->setDoNotUseCategoryId(true);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

and use that to display the items from your `local.xml`

```
<reference name="right">
   <block type="[module]/related name="category_related" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Comment: I guess there's no way to do this without creating a module? :)

Comment: You can add the PHP code to a view file but I highly recomment against it